# How to change directory to `g:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.32`?

Tags: windows-xp, mysql, command-line

In the Windows XP command prompt...

I can use `chdir` to access `g:\wamp\bin\mysql\`.

I am unable to use `chdir` to access `g:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.32`.

Does the `5.1.32` need special attention?

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Comment: Are you sure mysql5.1.32 is a directory or is it a file with the extension hidden?

Comment: Have you tried `cd`ing to `G:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5*`?

Comment: `mysql5.1.32` is a directory.

Comment: Nothing seems to happen when I try it. I have tried `cd g:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the short name for the folder. From its parent, enter "dir /x" to show the short (8.3) names for the folder contents. There should be a short name for the folder you want, somewhere in the directory list.  Try CD'ing to that.  For instance, the short name for "C:\Program files" on most Windows XP systems is "C:\PROGRA~1".